# Ansible and restarting a docker service

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm currently managing my Docker services using Ansible. The images are managed by a Docker Compose file which is in `/opt/ipaccess/docker/`.

My update process is as follows:

1. Stop services

   ```
   docker_service: project_src=/opt/ipaccess/docker/ state=absent
   ```
2. Upload new docker images and load them
3. Start services

   ```
   docker_service: project_src=/opt/ipaccess/docker/ state=present
   ```

What I'm looking for is a way to only stop/start what I've uploaded (this I know as the impacted services are known in the playbook context).

I've read the documentation online but it's not clear how to tell docker_service module to only stop/start a particular service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is untested and seems to be undocumented.

Looking at the docs it *seems* like there is no way to do this. However, if we look at the [code for the docker_service module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/cloud/docker/docker_service.py#L926) (specifically the restart command `cmd_restart`) it looks like it takes a list of services or a falsey value (falsey value causing it to restart all services). This command is only called by the `cmd_up` function, so we need `state=present` too.

So based on that, I'd expect:

```
docker_service:
    project_src: /opt/ipaccess/docker/
    services:
        - db
        - web
        - myotherservice
    restarted: true
    state: present
```

To restart the listed services only.

Let me know if that works for you, if so we should get those docs updated with a PR. If not post your error and we can work from there.